# Is Synaptic better than the Software Center?

Tags: software-center, synaptic

Please forgive me for this novice question.

Most old experienced users of Ubuntu says that Synaptic Package Manager is the best way of installing software on the Ubuntu systems.

Is it because the granular control that Synaptic provides to it's users for installing the software?

Comment: Best way to install software is a simple: sudo apt-get install abc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well these two solutions are quite different. While Ubuntu Software Centre is very user friendly, it has some disadvantages:

- Some packages are hidden
- It's quite slow

Synaptic is a tool for power users. It gives you access to all available packages. However it will not protect user from his own mistakes (for example uninstalling some essential package). And, of course, it's not user friendly at all.